# SockJS connections in a clustered Vert.x environment

Tags: vert.x, sockjs

The vertx application runs in Docker containers, on two EC2 instances and is clustered.

Clustering is achieved with the `hazelcast-aws` plugin and the application is started like this:

```
docker run --name ... -p ... \
--network ... \
-v ... \
-d ... \
-c 'exec java \
-Dvertx.eventBus.options.setClustered=true \
-Dvertx.eventBus.options.setClusterPort=15701 \
-jar ... -conf ... \
-cluster'
```

Nothing cluster-related is set programmatically.

Client opens a socket on the first request and uses it for future similar requests.
Each request will:

1. initiate an async request with the server by publishing a message to the event bus
2. register a consumer on the event bus which will handle the result of the above,
   and which is passed a reference to the socket connection where it should send the result to

Since vertx does round robin by default when clustered and there are two instances, this means any instance gets every other message (from 1., above) and makes the client, which connects to one instance only, receive exactly half of all expected responses.

I suppose this is because, even though the registered consumer has a reference to the socket object, it can't use it because it was created on a different node/webserver.

Would that be correct and is there a way to get 100% of messages to the client, connected to just one node, without introducing things like RabbitMQ?

Here's the SockJS handler code:

```
SockJSHandler sockJSHandler = SockJSHandler.create(vertx, new SockJSHandlerOptions());
sockJSHandler.socketHandler(socket -> {
    SecurityService securityService = (SecurityService) ServiceFactory.getService(SecurityService.class);
    if (securityService.socketHeadersSecurity(socket)) {
        socket.handler(socketMessage -> {
            try {
                LOGGER.trace("socketMessage: " + socketMessage);
                Socket socket = Json.decodeValue(socketMessage.toString(), Socket.class);
                Report report = socket.getReport();
                if (report != null) {
                    Account accountRequest = socket.getAccount();
                    Account accountDatabase = accountRequest == null ? null
                            : ((AccountService) ServiceFactory.getService(AccountService.class)).getById(accountRequest.getId());
                    Response result = securityService.socketReportSecurity(accountRequest, accountDatabase, report) ?
                            ((ReportService) ServiceFactory.getService(ReportService.class)).createOrUpdateReport(report, accountDatabase)
                            : new Response(Response.unauthorized);
                    if (Response.success.equals(result.getResponse())) {
                        //register a consumer
                        String consumerName = "report.result." + Timestamp.from(ClockFactory.getClock().instant());
                        vertx.eventBus().consumer(consumerName, message -> {
                            Response executionResult;
                            if ("success".equals(message.body())) {
                                try {
                                    Path csvFile = Paths.get(config.getString(Config.reportPath.getConfigName(), Config.reportPath.getDefaultValue())
                                            + "/" + ((Report) result.getPayload()).getId() + ".csv");
                                    executionResult = new Response(new JsonObject().put("csv", new String(Files.readAllBytes(csvFile))));
                                } catch (IOException ioEx) {
                                    executionResult = new Response(new Validator("Failed to read file.", ioEx.getMessage(), null, null));
                                    LOGGER.error("Failed to read file.", ioEx);
                                }
                            } else {
                                executionResult = new Response(new Validator("Report execution failed", (String)message.body(), null, null));
                            }
                            //send second message to client
                            socket.write(Json.encode(executionResult));
                            vertx.eventBus().consumer(consumerName).unregister();
                        });
                        //order report execution
                        vertx.eventBus().send("report.request", new JsonObject()
                                .put("reportId", ((Report) result.getPayload()).getId())
                                .put("consumerName", consumerName));
                    }
                    //send first message to client
                    socket.write(Json.encode(result));
                } else {
                    LOGGER.info("Insufficient data sent over socket: " + socketMessage.toString());
                    socket.end();
                }
            } catch (DecodeException dEx) {
                LOGGER.error("Error decoding message.", dEx);
                socket.end();
            }
        });
    } else {
        LOGGER.info("Illegal socket connection attempt from: " + socket.remoteAddress());
        socket.end();
    }
});
mainRouter.route("/websocket/*").handler(sockJSHandler);
```

Interestingly, when running two nodes clustered on localhost the client gets 100% of the results.

EDIT:
This was not a SockJS but a configuration issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since vertx does round robin by default when clustered and there are
> two instances, this means any instance gets every other message (from
> 1., above) and makes the client, which connects to one instance only, receive exactly half of all expected responses.

This assumption is only partially correct. Vert.x does round-robin, yes, but this means each instance will get half of the connections, not half of the messages.

Once connection is established, all its messages will arrive to a single instance.

So this:

> Would that be correct and is there a way to get 100% of messages to
> the client, connected to just one node, without introducing things
> like RabbitMQ?

Already happens.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Alexey. Turns out, I had a configuration problem, so my question was not a good lead and the problem was unrelated to SockJS. I would delete it but people might find your comment useful.